# Is it possible to define a content root folder?

Tags: r, bookdown

#### Is it possible to use a root "content" folder to keep all your Rmd files and associated images or drawings.

I was trying to use the following structure

```
bookdown-project
  *.yml
  *.sh
  *.css
  content/*.Rmd
  content/diagrams/*.png
```

**_bookdown.yml**

```
book_filename: "demo"
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: ""
    number_sections: false
    numbering: false
rmd_subdir: ["content"]
delete_merged_file: true
```

*Running the bookdown render gives the following output*

```
> bookdown::render_book("content/index.Rmd", "bookdown::gitbook")

> Error in bookdown::render_book("content/index.Rmd",
> "bookdown::gitbook") :    No input R Markdown files found from the
> current directory /Users/Jerry/Code/bookdown-project or in the
> rmd_files field of _bookdown.yml
```

So I used the rmd_files option as below

**_bookdown.yml**

```
book_filename: "demo"
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: ""
    number_sections: false
    numbering: false
rmd_subdir: true
rmd_files: ["content/index.Rmd", "content/01-intro.Rmd", "content/02-features.Rmd", "content/03-modules.Rmd"]
delete_merged_file: true
```

The book is generated, but the referenced image files are missing.

for example in content/02-features.Rmd I had the following line

```
![](diagrams/feature-mindmap.png)
```

but I noticed that the images are not copied. If I move the diagrams folder up into the root as shown below, the diagrams appear in the rendered formats.

```
bookdown-project
  content/*.Rmd
  diagrams/*.png
```

This works, but it breaks the relative location of the files.

If there was an option to set the content root like below and all files take the relative path, it would be easier to separate the configuration for bookdown from the actual content being written. Maybe this is already there, but I couldn't find it. I tried

```
content_root: ["content"]
```

---

```
devtools::session_info('bookdown')
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 system   x86_64, darwin17.6.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.2.830)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  C                           
 tz       Asia/Kolkata                
 date     2018-08-24                  

Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source                           
 backports   1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 bookdown    0.7.17  2018-08-24 Github (rstudio/bookdown@4f9d73d)
 digest      0.6.15  2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 evaluate    0.11    2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 glue        1.3.0   2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 graphics  * 3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                            
 grDevices * 3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                            
 highr       0.7     2018-06-09 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 jsonlite    1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 knitr       1.20    2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 magrittr    1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 markdown    0.8     2017-04-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 methods   * 3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                            
 mime        0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 Rcpp        0.12.18 2018-07-23 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 rmarkdown   1.10    2018-06-11 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 rprojroot   1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 stats     * 3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                            
 stringi     1.2.4   2018-07-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 stringr     1.3.1   2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 tinytex     0.7     2018-08-22 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 tools       3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                            
 utils     * 3.5.1   2018-07-03 local                            
 xfun        0.3     2018-07-06 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                   
 yaml        2.2.0   2018-07-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
```